# How to manipulate JSON Response in Spring RestController

Tags: json, spring-boot, response, spring-restcontroller

I would like to change the JSON Response of my Spring RestController.

This is the controller:

```
 @RestController
public class SomeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @GetMapping("/something/{someparam}")
    SomeRecord bySomeparam(@PathVariable String someparam) {

        try {
            return service.findBySomeparam(someparam);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(
                      HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "No Something found with this someparam!"
                    );
        }

    }
}
```

The current response looks like this:

```
{
    "fookey": "Foovalue",
    "barkey": "Barvalue",
    "bafkey": "Bafvalue"
}
```

I would like my response to look like this:

```
HTTP-STATUS: 200

{

  Fookey: Foovalue      

  Barkey: Barvalue

  Bafkey: Bafvalue

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ResponseEntity
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-entity